# Windows Server Domain User and Workstation Software

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

I have a new server with windows server 2012(domain) and want to add a few new users and workstations( with AD), so all user could login on all workstations. That is easy, but now I would like to add a few software like office, pdf reader, video player etc. so that all users could use them on all workstation (on all the same). How could I do that?

Should I install all the software on all workstation or is there any other solutions. I ask because I would like to update (if any software need a update) the software on all workstations at the same time so I does not need to update each workstation separately, so all workstation get the update.

Whats the best solution.
If you have any question please feel free to ask.

Comment: This is off-topic because it's not a programming question. [Sf] might be a better fit but check their help centre.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I get it now how to do it.
I know that the question is out off-topic and  I give any answer to my own question but...

I have to use the GPO (Group Policy object)! That helps to deploy the software on all workstations so I don't have to install it on all the workstation seperately :)